# How to round connection for Matplotlib axis spines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is a fairly simple question. I am working on creating a Matplotlib figure that has several inset axes.

I have removed the tick marks so that the inset spines of each of the inset axes meet at a 90 degree angle. However, when you add a legend to this figure, it adds a legend object that has slightly rounded spine connections for each "edge" of the legend object.

Is there an easy way to get a similar effect for the spines of an inset axis or axis more generally?

My code:

```
fig, e = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
    
a = e.inset_axes([.1, .1, .1, .2])
b = e.inset_axes([.3, .1, .1, .2])

for ax in [a, b]:
    
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xticks([])
```

Current output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code you used to add the legend?

Comment: @HåkonHægland The code for the legend is just the default of `ax.legend()`

Comment: The legend object doesn't have spines. It has something like a [`FancyBboxPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch.html).  A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67390756/rounded-corners-for-axes-in-matplotlib) has been stayed unanswered, which probably means there isn't an easy way.

Comment: @JohanC Interesting. Thank you for this clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea is to hide the spines, and draw a [`FancyBboxPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch.html) at the same spot. Setting `clip_on=False` avoids that the box would be clipped inappropriately.

Assigning the rounded box to the `ax_a.patch` makes the clipping both of the main ax and of the objects inside the inset ax work.

Here is example code modifying the left inset axis.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import FancyBboxPatch
import numpy as np

fig, ax_e = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

ax_a = ax_e.inset_axes([.1, .1, .1, .2])
ax_b = ax_e.inset_axes([.3, .1, .1, .2])

for ax in [ax_a, ax_b]:
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xticks([])
for s in ax_a.spines:
    ax_a.spines[s].set_visible(False)
p_bbox = FancyBboxPatch((0, 0), 1, 1,
                        boxstyle="round,pad=-0.0040,rounding_size=0.2",
                        ec="black", fc="white", clip_on=False, lw=1,
                        mutation_aspect=1,
                        transform=ax_a.transAxes)
ax_a.add_patch(p_bbox)
ax_a.patch = p_bbox

t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
ax_a.plot(np.sin(3 * t), np.sin(4 * t))  # drawing some curve
ax_a.plot([-2, 2], [-2, 2], 'g', lw=10, alpha=0.3)  # diagonal line to check the clipping in the corners
ax_a.set_xlim(-1.1, 1.1)
ax_a.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)

ax_e.set_facecolor('tomato')  # show the clipping around the inset axes

plt.show()
```

[image: inset axis with rounded corners]